# SQL Table to SiteMapProvider 4 ASP.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I have been trying to use SiteMapProvider from NuGet and make it link to a database in order to get all the links for a sidebar and breadcrumb, so far I don't find any tutorial, and I keep getting stuck using the information to the xml file, I am sure that I have to create a class, but I don't seem to find any tutorial on how to do this, or how to correctly make the call to this class, is there a tutorial or any website that contain this information? I have been trying to do what is included in here:

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps

But I don't know how to define the dynamicNodeProvider, any help? Sorry if it's some what vague what I am asking.. I have tried to search but I haven't find any information..

EDIT:

I was able to load information using :

```
    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "HOLDCREATEREPORT", ParentKey = "Home", Key = "CreateReport")]
```

on each, class, but I am more interested in doing this using a unique class that loads all nodes, I have tried so far to change the sitemap xml to the following code:

navigation itself has the following code:

```
public class navigation : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {


        DynamicNode dynamicnode = new DynamicNode();
        dynamicnode.Title = "test"+ i.ToString();
        dynamicnode.ParentKey = "Home";
        dynamicnode.RouteValues.Add("test" + i.ToString(), "abcdb"+ i.ToString());

        yield return dynamicnode;
        }
    }
}
```

yet when I run it nothing gets displayed, I am pretty sure I am missing something extremely easy >_>.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for `MvcSiteMapProvider` version 3.x. If you are using the latest version of 4.x, you should refer to the [4.x documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-Sitemap-Nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider).

Comment: Hello NightOwl, I have been reading your tutorial, I was able to display using:

        [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "HOLDCREATEREPORT", ParentKey = "Home", Key = "Checkout")] 

yet my goald is to load all nodes from a class.. I have updated first post.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Node Providers require a definition node. The definition node can either be in XML or as a .NET attribute. It won't be included in the `SiteMap`, but the nodes that the Dynamic Node Provider create will be.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Dynamic Nodes", DynamicNodeProvider = "MyNamespace.navigation, MyAssembly")]
```

### Or

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Dynamic Nodes" dynamicNodeProvider="MyNamespace.navigation, MyAssembly">
```

Comment: Thanks again NightOwl, I Was able to solve it,  I created to mvcSiteMapNodes, one being the root, and one being the dynamic node now it looks like this:

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" key ="0" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title ="test"   dynamicNodeProvider="MvcApplication2.Controllers.navigation, MvcApplication2" />


I am now trying to add fontawesome into it, and defining how MenuHelperModel.cshtml, will look, I am pretty sure fontawesome is loaded through an attribute, do you have any tutorial to point me out :D!?

Comment: No tutorial, but you can edit the HTML that the helpers output by changing the views in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/`.